# find list2 in list1 in mvc

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Friends, how to search in a list one with link commands, and if there is an item from list two, set the value ischecked‌ true‌:

```
var list1 =  _context.Product()
                                  .Select(x => new Product()
                                  {
                                      Id = x.Id,
                                      IsChecked=false
                                  })
                                  .ToList();
```

list1.Where(item => !list2.Any(item2 => item2.Id == item.Id));

Comment: Is there any link between the lists? Try to share sample input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Something as follows:

```
var list1 = new List<string> { 'USA', 'Canada', 'Japan', 'Sweden' };
var list2 = new List<string> { 'Sweden', 'USA' };

bool result = list1.Any(c => list2.Contains(c)); //Check if list 1 contains any value from list 2

if(result)
{
  //Logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list1 = new List<string> [{ 'USA',false}, {'Canada',flase}, {'Japan', false},{'Sweden',false }];
```

var list2 = new List { 'Sweden', 'USA' };

and when query executed :

```
var list1=new List<string> [{ 'USA',true}, {'Canada',flase}, {'Japan', false},{'Sweden',true}];
```